# mirth sending message to different sever

Tags: hl7, mirth

I have 2 server hosted on network.One is having Labdaq and other is having Medisoft.
I want to send all the hl7 messages dropped by labDaq into a folder that medisoft is looking.How can i do that with Mirth.i want to setup with connectivity mode of File reader and writer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You've described exactly how to achieve this in the question. The source connector on your channel should be of type File Reader, and your destination is a File Writer. If you're not performing any transformations on the HL7, the only things to consider are the number of messages per file, and the permissions the Mirth Connect service user has on each of the machines.

Comment: Thanks Lee for replying.The problem i am having is suppose i have a shared drived z.So  under the destination path i can not simply mention Z.because it will not detect with z.so what information under destination path i should enter.

Comment: If you can't access the shared drive by its share name (e.g. Z:), you'll need to find out its physical/virtual location and refer to it using that, e.g. "\\shared_server\c$" in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a two line program, not sure why you want to use a whole middleware to move files between folders.

But, if you want to do it anyway, create a channel with File Reader Source and File Writer Destination. There you can configure both folders.